# Telegram bot doesn't send message to one of my groups

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, node-cron

I've built a telegram bot using Node.js to send a text message on specific times. So, I have 2 groups: one for testing and other to actually run it. It runs perfectly on testing group but it doesn't respond when it is supposed to run on my actual group. I've got the both `chatId` from Telegram Web's link. So what can be possibly wrong?

- Bot is an admin in both groups
- My account is also an admin, but I'm not the creator of the actual group however what I can do everything in my actual group except adding new admins & remain anonymous.
- Disabled privacy settings from BotFather

**The code**

```js
const telegramBot = require("node-telegram-bot-api");
const token = "THE_API_KEY";
const bot = new telegramBot(token, { polling: true });
const cron = require('node-cron');

let chatId = -111111111;
cron.schedule('59 6 15 * * 2', () => {
    bot.sendMessage(chatId, "some string value");
    },{
      scheduled: true,
      timezone: "Etc/UTC"
    });

cron.schedule('59 1 12 * * 7', () => {
  bot.sendMessage(chatId, "some different string value");
  },{
    scheduled: true,
    timezone: "Etc/UTC"
  });
  
  // The part below this comment line works perfectly fine on both groups
  
  bot.on("message", msg => {
  const chatId = msg.chat.id;
  const message = msg.text.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
  
  switch (message) {
    case "xx":
      bot.sendMessage(chatId, "text");
      break;
    case "xx":
      bot.sendMessage(
        chatId,
        "text"
      );
      break;
    case "#whoareyou":
      bot.sendMessage(
        chatId,
        "text"
      );
      break;
     }
   });
```

Comment: `chatId` is global to both cron, so both crons will send the text to the same `chatId`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I tried declaring that in their own scopes. In fact, tried to put the ID as a parameter but still no response on actually group.

Comment: It's not a matter of scope, it's a matter of `chatId` being `-111111111` no matter what. I assume you should have a different `chatId` for your testing group and for your "normal" group.

Comment: Ah my bad, all the crons you see here send a message to one group on different time using chatId. I've put the same chatId for both yet no response when I put my actual group's id.

Comment: It could be a lot of things and I'm no expert with Telegram, but you could do multiple things to narrow down the error and have valuable information: First, the `bot.sendMessage()` has a `catch` [callback](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/blob/master/doc/usage.md#error-handling) you could implement to see if the error comes from this function. You could also implement the `error` [event](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/blob/master/doc/usage.md#events), `bot.on('error', ...........`.

Comment: add the output to `console.log(bot.sendMessage)` function, to your question

Comment: Thank you all for your answers I solved it, in some cases you need to add -100 as a prefix to your channel/group's chatId. It was that simple lol